# FAQ questions (on the main site)

Tags: discussion, tags, site-faq

There are many questions which should be [faq](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) on the main site in my opinion. So I'm starting this meta post  to vote on questions  which could become [faq](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).  Add answers to propose faq questions, and vote on them, .

Comment: What would it mean for a bunch of questions to be FAQ at the end, just attaching the tag?

Comment: I see, but I think it is good to have such a list such that answers can be added and we can see if they get upvoted.

Comment: Another thing I'd ]to have here on physics SE too is a [Request for Reopen Votes](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/223/30967) meta post such as they have it on Math and MathOverflow. This would allow for a much more democratic (people with less then 3000 rep can take part too) and efficient procedure to reopen questions. The way we do it by discussing each question somebody thinks should get reopend separately at lenght just chokes the issue in a big overhead of unneeded political discussion and condiderations, and nothing gets reopend at the end.

Comment: I mean reopen a question should be much easier and straight forward than it currently is here on physics SE. On Math and MathOverflow they just wait and see if the suggestion to reopen a (corresponding answer) is supported, comments can be taken into account too, and if this is the case it gets reopend without lenghty discussions or making a large political fuzz out of the issue. That simple could life be ... :-)

Comment: I thought these questions should just get an FAQ tag and that's it, and now all of them are getting closed? With closing all of them I dont agree! The old questions which are just relatd to each other but not duplicates should be left alone.

Comment: There definitely should be one, like the good old usenet one: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/

Answer (score 3):

**[Quantum entanglement faster than speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/quantum-entanglement-faster-than-speed-of-light/)** and its multiple duplicates. We should choose a canonical question.

Answer (score 2):

**[How do Einstein's field equations come out of string theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44782/how-do-einsteins-field-equations-come-out-of-string-theory)**

- [The General Relativity from String Theory Point of View](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70060/the-general-relativity-from-string-theory-point-of-view?lq=1)
- [How does classical GR concept of space-time emerge from string theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/how-does-classical-gr-concept-of-space-time-emerge-from-string-theory?lq=1)
- [Is String Theory formulated in flat or curved spacetime?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44732/is-string-theory-formulated-in-flat-or-curved-spacetime?lq=1)
- [How does String Theory predict Gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30005/how-does-string-theory-predict-gravity?rq=1)
- [In what limit does string theory reproduce general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54317/in-what-limit-does-string-theory-reproduce-general-relativity?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

**[Why can't light escape from a classical black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/why-cant-light-escape-from-a-black-hole)**

- [Why is a black hole black?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28297/why-is-a-black-hole-black)
- [If nothing in the universe can travel faster than light, how come light can't escape a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41930/if-nothing-in-the-universe-can-travel-faster-than-light-how-come-light-cant-es?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

**[understanding time: Is time simply the rate change?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/understanding-time-is-time-simply-the-rate-change)**

- [Time, what is it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17056/time-what-is-it?lq=1)
- [What is a clock?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32155/what-is-a-clock?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

**[How does gravity escape a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/937/how-does-gravity-escape-a-black-hole)**

- [In which direction do gravitons travel? Do they originate from mass or are they collected by masses?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69651/in-which-direction-do-gravitons-travel-do-they-originate-from-mass-or-are-they)
- [Nothing escapes BHs, gravitons mediate gravity, so why do BHs gravitate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45999/nothing-escapes-bhs-gravitons-mediate-gravity-so-why-do-bhs-gravitate)
- [Why a black hole sucks nearly everything, but emits gravitons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35861/why-a-black-hole-sucks-nearly-everything-but-emits-gravitons)

[more...](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/937?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

**[How fast does gravity propagate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/the-speed-of-gravity)**

- [What is the speed of gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176157/what-is-the-speed-of-gravity)
- [Does gravity travel at the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26742/does-gravity-travel-at-the-speed-of-light)
- [How faster is the effect of force exerted by gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80442/how-faster-is-the-effect-of-force-exerted-by-gravity)
- [Gravity propagation speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104301/gravity-propagation-speed)
- [Time Delays in General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93795/time-delays-in-general-relativity)
- [Does gravity spread instantly?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12736/does-gravity-spread-instantly)
- [Does gravity act instantaneously?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103729/does-gravity-act-instantaneously)
- [Consequences of inverse square law with vast distances (Gravity); (in addition, is light speed broken)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114798/consequences-of-inverse-square-law-with-vast-distances-gravity-in-addition)
- [Is gravity instantaneous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170001/is-gravity-instantaneous)
- [Gravitational Effect Versus the Speed of Light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/87835/gravitational-effect-versus-the-speed-of-light)
- [How quickly does gravity extend from created mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142144/how-quickly-does-gravity-extend-from-created-mass)
- [Will we feel the gravity of a star 10 light years away for the next 10 years if, somehow, it vanishes today from its position?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118472/will-we-feel-the-gravity-of-a-star-10-light-years-away-for-the-next-10-years-if)
- [Time taken for gravity of a distant object to interact with a newly created particle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51646/time-taken-for-gravity-of-a-distant-object-to-interact-with-a-newly-created-part)
- [How fast does gravitational information travel?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/how-fast-does-gravitational-information-travel)
- [Solar Catastrophe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60790/solar-catastrophe)
- [Gravity Concept Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134446/gravity-concept-question)
- [Is the curvature of spacetime in General Relativity instantaneous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/370058/is-the-curvature-of-spacetime-in-general-relativity-instantaneous)
- [Is the influence of gravity greater than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169501/is-the-influence-of-gravity-greater-than-light)
- [If Sun disappeared and we wouldn't notice until 8 mins later, then would we notice the gravitational force sudden disappearance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/331108/if-sun-disappeared-and-we-wouldnt-notice-until-8-mins-later-then-would-we-noti)
- [Do the changes of gravity travel across distances instantly or limited to the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/40968/do-the-changes-of-gravity-travel-across-distances-instantly-or-limited-to-the-sp)
- [How much time does it take to affect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55731/how-much-time-does-it-take-to-affect)
- ["Speed" of Gravity and Speed of Light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7041/speed-of-gravity-and-speed-of-light)
- [Why does gravity travel at the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374583/why-does-gravity-travel-at-the-speed-of-light)

**[Do gravitational waves travel faster than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235450/do-gravitational-waves-travel-faster-than-light)**

- [speed of gravitational waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107798/speed-of-gravitational-waves)
- [Speed of gravitational waves vs speed of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/254628/speed-of-gravitational-waves-vs-speed-of-light)
- [Is the speed of propagation of Einstein's gravitational waves unique?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282738/is-the-speed-of-propagation-of-einsteins-gravitational-waves-unique)

Also related:

- [What is the rate at which the field of an electron spreads?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143646/what-is-the-rate-at-which-the-field-of-an-electron-spreads)
- [Speed of a Graviton](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/356426/speed-of-a-graviton)
- [Does the reaction force appear without delay?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75196/does-the-reaction-force-appear-without-delay)
- [Faster Than Light Communication Using Gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38525/faster-than-light-communication-using-gravity)
- [Is Earth's orbit around the Sun affected by the ~8 minutes light delay?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62565/is-earths-orbit-around-the-sun-affected-by-the-8-minutes-light-delay)
- [What is the status of existing measurements of the speed of gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39260/what-is-the-status-of-existing-measurements-of-the-speed-of-gravity)
- [What is the speed of Newtonian gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187398/what-is-the-speed-of-newtonian-gravity)
- [How soon that a force affect another object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57137/how-soon-that-a-force-affect-another-object)
- [Is there a delay in the effect of the gravitational or electromagnetic force if a secondary body suddenly appears?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270444/is-there-a-delay-in-the-effect-of-the-gravitational-or-electromagnetic-force-if)
- [Do all the 4 forces of nature act at the same speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60037/do-all-the-4-forces-of-nature-act-at-the-same-speed)
- [Is it sure that gravitons are massless bosons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23760/is-it-sure-that-gravitons-are-massless-bosons)

Answer (score 0):

**[Variational Derivation of Schrodinger Equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69982/variational-derivation-of-schrodinger-equation)**

- [Lagrangian of Schrodinger field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15242/lagrangian-of-schrodinger-field?lq=1),
- [How would a Lagrangian be used to recover the Schrodinger equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55622/how-would-a-lagrangian-be-used-to-recover-the-schrodinger-equation?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**[How exactly do superstrings reduce the number of dimensions in bosonic string theory from 26 to 10 and remove the tachyons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48016/how-exactly-do-superstrings-reduce-the-number-of-dimensions-in-bosonic-string-th)**

- [Is this explanation of "Why nine space dimensions?" correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66930/is-this-explanation-of-why-nine-space-dimensions-correct?lq=1)
- [Why are extra dimensions necessary?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10527/why-are-extra-dimensions-necessary?lq=1)
- [Compactification of dimensions in string theory: Why our Universe has 3 large spatial dimensions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10075/compactification-of-dimensions?rq=1)
- [Why does string theory require 9 dimensions of space and one dimension of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31882/why-does-string-theory-require-9-dimensions-of-space-and-one-dimension-of-time?rq=1)
- [Limit on space-time dimension from susy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38722/limit-on-space-time-dimension-from-susy?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**[Why does string theory require 9 dimensions of space and one dimension of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31882/why-does-string-theory-require-9-dimensions-of-space-and-one-dimension-of-time?rq=1)**

- [Why are extra dimensions necessary?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10527/why-are-extra-dimensions-necessary/10654#10654)
- [Is this explanation of "Why nine space dimensions?" correct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66930/is-this-explanation-of-why-nine-space-dimensions-correct)

Answer (score 0):

**[How exactly does curved space-time describe the force of gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3009/how-exactly-does-curved-space-time-describe-the-force-of-gravity)**

- [Does the curvature of spacetime theory assume gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7781/does-the-curvature-of-spacetime-theory-assume-gravity/69092#69092)
- [How do the Einstein's differential equation of the curvature of spacetime come out of Einstein's field equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45307/how-do-the-einsteins-differential-equation-of-the-curvature-of-spacetime-come-o/71454#71454)

Answer (score 0):

**[Why one-dimensional strings, but not higher-dimensional shells/membranes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55431/why-one-dimensional-strings-but-not-higher-dimensional-shells-membranes)**

- [Does string/M-theory address higher-dimensional membrane vibration modes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73808/does-string-m-theory-address-higher-dimensional-membrane-vibration-modes?lq=1)
- [String theory: why not use $n$-dimensional blocks/objects/branes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66948/string-theory-why-not-use-n-dimensional-blocks-objects-branes?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**[Is it possible to recover Classical Mechanics from Schrödinger's equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17651/is-it-possible-to-recover-classical-mechanics-from-schrodingers-equation)**

- [From Quantum Mechanics to Classical Mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108222/from-quantum-mechanics-to-classical-mechanics)
- [Can the laws of classical mechanics be derived from quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74333/can-the-laws-of-classical-mechanics-be-derived-from-quantum-mechanics)
- [How to go from Quantum World to Classical World?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44926/how-to-go-from-quantum-world-to-classical-world)
- [Classical limit of quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32112/classical-limit-of-quantum-mechanics)
- [When does $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ provide a valid transition from quantum to classcial mechanics? When and why does it fail?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56151/when-does-hbar-rightarrow-0-provide-a-valid-transition-from-quantum-to-class)
- [Why do we obtain classical physics by taking the limit of Planck's constant to zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218523/why-do-we-obtain-classical-physics-by-taking-the-limit-of-plancks-constant-to-z)
- [Does limit $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ in Quantum Mechanics mean anything?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102082/does-limit-hbar-rightarrow-0-in-quantum-mechanics-mean-anything)
- [Classical Limit of Schrodinger Equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33767/classical-limit-of-schrodinger-equation)
- [Classical Limit in Quantum Mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82962/classical-limit-in-quantum-mechanics)
- [Can Newton's laws be explained by Quantum Physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/can-newtons-laws-be-explained-by-quantum-physics)
- [How to prove Newton's second law with quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77294/how-to-prove-newtons-second-law-with-quantum-mechanics)